# Drag and drop list with web-components, lit-element, polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, lit-element

I am trying to create a simple list of 'cards' that I can re-order by dragging and dropping.

I came across [this fluid-grid web component](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@fluidnext-polymer/paper-grid) and have had some success. I have created a list of cards and I can drag them around. The problem is, how to handle the 'drop' event so that I can update the location of the dropped item in the list.

Here is my code:

```
import {LitElement, html, customElement, property, css} from 'lit-element';
import { repeat } from 'lit-html/directives/repeat'
import '@fluidnext-polymer/paper-grid';
import '@polymer/paper-card/paper-card'

interface VaadinRouterLocation {
  baseUrl?: string
  params?: {
    id: string
  }
  pathname?: string
  route?: {
    path: string
    component: string
    search: string
  }
}
@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    :host {
      display: block;
      border: solid 1px gray;
      padding: 16px;
      max-width: 800px;
    }
  `;

  @property({type: Object})
  location:VaadinRouterLocation = {};
  constructor() {
    super(); 
  }
  @property({type: Array})
  tasks = [
    {"name": "Task 1", "sequence": 1, "id": "A"},
    {"name": "Task 2", "sequence": 2, "id": "B"},
    {"name": "Task 3", "sequence": 3, "id": "C"},
  ] 
  render() {
    return html`
      <div id="container" @ondrop="(e) => console.log(e.target)">
        <paper-grid animated id="grid" draggable cell-margin="5" col-count="2" row-count="${this.tasks.length}" ondrop="(e) => console.log(e.target)">
        ${repeat(this.tasks, (task) => html`
          <paper-card col="0" row=${task.sequence} height="1" width="1" @drop="${this.handleDrop}">
              <div class="card-content">${task.name}</div>
            </paper-card>
        `)}
        </paper-grid>
    </div>
    `
  }


  handleDrop(e:any) {
    console.log("Event", e)
  }
  allowDrop(e:any){
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'my-element': MyElement;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In LitElement you don't need the `on...` prefix. Replace `@ondrop` and `ondrop` with `@drop` - currently that's only on the `<paper-card>` element.

Also note that if you want to access the elements being dragged over you may need to use `e.relatedTarget.getRootNode().host` to get the actual custom element, as the event fires from an element that may be nested in the shadow DOM for your component.